# How to include Category product to GetAll

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor

I have null ref ex when i try to get CAtegory my Product. i`m used Repository and UnitOfWork pattern. If you need more code - I can send. Presumably this is because the controller can't get a Category or CoverType object.

Shoppping cart Model:
public class ShoppingCart
{
public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    

    [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value between 1 and 1000")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
    //NEW
    public decimal FactTime { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    
  
}
```

CartController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        ShoppingCartVM = new ShoppingCartVM()
        {

            ListCart = _unitOfWork.ShoppingCart.GetAll(u => u.ApplicationUserId == claim.Value,
            includeProperties: "Product"),
            OrderHeader = new()
        };
        foreach(var cart in ShoppingCartVM.ListCart)
        {
            
            cart.Price = GetPriceBasedOnQuantity(cart.Count, cart.Product.Price);
            ShoppingCartVM.OrderHeader.OrderTotal += (cart.Price * cart.Count);
        }

        return View(ShoppingCartVM);
    }
```

Product Model:

```
 public int Id { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Task Type")]
    public int TaskTypeId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public TaskType TaskType { get; set; }


    public string? Description { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string? Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 10000)]
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal? OrientedTime { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public string? ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Cover Type")]
    public int? CoverTypeId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public CoverType CoverType { get; set; }
}
```

Repository GetAll Model:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter=null, string? includeProperties = null)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach(var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProp);
            }
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You need to do a `ThenInclude` for `CoverType` after doing `Include` for `Product`

Comment: I can`t select "Include" or "ThenInclude" after method "GetAll"(

Comment: You'll have to change your GetAll code, it doesn't allow for ThenInclude.

To be honest, just do something like, add a new parameter to the method

`Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> includes`. Instead of the string includes. Replace the includes code with `includes?.`Invoke(query);` then call it with `GetAll(.., query => query.Include(..).ThenInclude(..)`